# Google maps javascript api v3 not working on Nexus 7 , LG 4.0, micromax 4.1

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I have created one application using Google maps javascript API v3, phonegap 2.6.0, Jquery mobile 1.2.0. In this application I am displayed the hospital list and their desired distance and duration between user's current location and hospital using Google direction services( also try using distance matrix service). This application working fine in 2.2 & Gingerbird( samsung 2.3.6). But when I tried to run this application on android Ice cream sandwhich & jelly bean(Nexus 7, Micromax 4.1, Lg Optimus 4.0, HTC desire 4.0.3), it is not working . when i debugging my application I show the  alert statement before the Google direction service object is pop up,but after the  Google  direction service alert is not  pop up. so my question is Google direction services  or distance matrix service working or not in jelly bean & sandwhich version. I have simply display the records using  jquery mobile list view with distance & duration.

please give me proper guidelines so my application worked on higher version.

here is my code..

```
alert('start route'); <----pop up
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var request = {
    origin : new google.maps.LatLng(cLat, cLng),
    destination : new google.maps.LatLng(destination_lat, destination_long),
    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
alert('end route'); <----Not pop up
```

or

```
alert('start route');<----pop up
var Service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
var request = {
    origin : new google.maps.LatLng(cLat, cLng),
    destination : new google.maps.LatLng(destination_lat, destination_long),
    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};`enter code here`
alert('end route');<----Not pop up
```

Regards,
Amar Patel